# Voltage drop on resistor with MOSFET configuration circuit

Tags: voltage, mosfet, resistors, ohms-law

I have big misunderstanding in calculating voltage and current across resistor in next circuit. I think picture well represent my question.

[image]

The amplitude of V1 is 3.3 V.

Comment: That's probably not enough to turn that FET on even if it were low side.

Comment: It would be helpful to show all waveforms, stimulus, and why you expect certain values.. e.g. expected 9.6V. Why do you expect that? More info is better.

Answer (score 4):

N-channel mosfets don't work for high-side switching - you need a high voltage (gate threshold + load voltage) on the gate to open it reliably. Otherwise it is going to have unpredictable results which depend on the specific mosfet you use. You should put your mosfet so that it switches ground to the load, and then your calculations would make sense.

Comment: You can use an NMOS as a high side switch, its just that it requires bootstrapping. There are also plenty of commercially available high side NMOS switch ICs. The reason youd want one is that they rely on electron mobility, which is higher than PMOS's hole mobility. That means the same current can be achieved with lower Vgs, which gets us to the advantage: lower saturation Vds. Less voltage wasted on the FET, which may be crucial depending on the application.

Answer (score 1):

Most N-Mos Mosfets need the gate voltage to be 10V higher than the source voltage to be turned on. If you want the source voltage to be 9.6V then the gate voltage must be 19.6V. But your Mosfet has no part number for us to see its Vgs specs.

Answer (score 0):

First, here's calculation of the power consumption on `R1.

$$ P_2 = \frac{V_2 ^ 2}{R_2} \times 0.8 $$

To give same power consumption with steady DC current and voltage,

$$ P_2 = \frac{V_{2eq}^2}{R_2} $$

$$ V_{2eq} = \sqrt{0.8} \times V_2 = 10.73V $$

If your simulation result still shows 11mV, I am not able to figure it out. I think it should be 11V.

Thus, the simulation result will be 10.73V.